# Can you apply a CSS hover effect to an element that’s not a child of the hovered element?

Tags: css, html, hover, background-color

I was not sure if this is possible or not. I am working in CSS3 animations right now and I need to hover on a link that will effect other div element(non-child) on the page. I was not sure if there is a work around or not.

```
<style type="text/css">

#header {
 background-color:red;
}

#header:hover .element {
 background-color:blue;
}

.element {
 background-color:green;
}

</style>
```

-

```
<header id="header">
     <li><a href="#">Hover</a></li>
</header>

<div class="element" >
 <p>hello world </p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you verify i tried it on chrome and firefox. and it does not. :/

Comment: That won't work because your 2nd rule is saying when I find an element with the class `element` inside of an element with the class of `bgchange` which is currently being hovered over, inside of an element with the ID `header` apply this rule to it. And this does not reflect the HTML you provide.

Comment: ok I ripped out the "bgchange" class so it is easier to read.

Answer (score 28):

Since these are adjacent siblings, you can use the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators): `+`.

```
#header:hover + .element {
 background-color:blue;
}
```

This is well supported in most modern browsers*. IE7 can be buggy. IE6 and below does not support it.

* One of the other answers mentions the general sibling selector, which does not work in Webkit when used with a dynamic pseudo-class like `:hover` due to [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12520). Take note that this same bug will cause problems in Webkit if you attempt to stack adjacent sibling selectors with a dynamic pseudo-class. For example, `#this:hover + sibling + sibling` will not work in Webkit.

Comment: Very nice! Yes '+' does work. This question has produced two good solutions. The '+' answers this question, but the '~' will be good for future reference once the webkit team fixes that bug.

Comment: Also, this wasn't working for me until I realized that the sibling in question has to be after (in the html) the element hovered upon.

Answer (score 20):

There is the [general sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) (`~`) that selects sibling elements.

So with the HTML you’ve posted, `#header:hover ~ .element` would select `<div class="element">` when it’s a subsequent sibling of the hovered header.

[Even IE 7 supports it](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/~_%28general_sibling_selector%29), so you're on relatively solid ground.

Comment: I'll investigate sibling selectors for webkit.

Comment: how can i select the elements that come before the element ? ~ just selects elements that come after it.

Answer (score 2):

Re the sibling selector webkit bug, this article has a css only workaround:

> http://css-tricks.com/webkit-sibling-bug/

Quoting:

```
body { -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s; }
@-webkit-keyframes bugfix { from { padding: 0; } to { padding: 0; } }
```

Above creates an animation on the page and this magically seems to fix the problem. The above can be added directly to main css or a create a webkit only stylesheet to go with your ie hacks one.

Would recommend the webkit only stylesheet something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)" href="webkit.css"/>
```

as it hides it from other browsers and can be more easily removed in the future once the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this will not work unless your .element class is within the .bgchange element.  That's the nature of the cascade: you cannot (through CSS alone) affect DOM elements that are structurally / heirarchically removed from each other.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so. This construction: #header .bgchange:hover .element indicates that .element is inside the .bgchange. I guess this one needs JS